# Regression vs Classification for a problem that could be solved by both

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, classification

I have a problem that I have been treating as a classification problem. I am trying to predict whether a machine will pass or fail a particular test based on a number of input features.

What I am really interested in is actually whether a new machine is predicted to pass or fail the test. It can pass or fail the test by having certain signatures (such as speed, vibration etc) go out of range.

Therefore, I could either:

1) Treat it as a pure regression problem; try to predict the actual values of speed, vibration etc

2) Treat it as a pure classification problem; for each observation, feed in whether it passed or failed on the labels, and try to predict this in the tool I am making

3) Treat it as a pseudo problem; where I predict the actual value, and come up with some measure of how confident I am that it is a pass or fail based on distance from the threshold of pass/fail

To be clear; I am working on a real problem. I am not interested in getting a super precise prediction of a certain value, just whether a machine is predicted to pass or fail (and bonus extension; how likely that it is to be true).

I have been working with classification model as I only have a couple hundred observations and some previous research showed that this might be the best way to treat the problem. However I am wondering now whether this is the right thing to do.

What would you do!?

Many thanks.

Comment: Because it's more about theory, this would be a better question for the [stats.se] or [datascience.se] stack sites. That being said, it's going to largely depend on what your end goal is. Your model should aim to predict the outcome you're trying to use. Are you trying to predict fail/notfail? Classification. Are you trying to predict individual component failure? multilabel classification. Predicting whether a component will go overspeed? Possibly regression.

Comment: My ultimate aim is to predict the pass/fail; but I do not really care if the best way to do that 'generally speaking' is to try to predict a more precise value of a parameter and work out if that is a pass or fail from there. I was wondering if anyone had any prior experience with how to treat such a problem especially where I do not have a large dataset...

Comment: In my work as a military nuclear engineer, probability of failure was generally considered as very important - for example, we would replace functional, working machinery parts precisely *because* we knew the probability of failure after a given service life for the component. I would be inclined to go with your choice number 3 for this reason.

Comment: Great, thank you that is valuable insight. In my particular case also; it would still be useful to be able to rank the machines in order of 'probability of pass/fail'. I was initially trying to do this via a predict_proba_ on my classification attempt; but it will be simpler to do this with some measure of distance of parameter from my pass/fail threshold. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Without having the data and running classification or regression, a comparison would be hard **because of the metric you use for each family is different**. 
For example, comparing RMSE of a regression with F1 score (or accuracy) of a classification problem would be apple to orange comparison.

**It would be ideal if you can train a good regression model (low RMSE) because that would give you information more than the original pass/fail question.** From my past experiences with industrial customers,

**First**, train all 3 models you have mentioned and **then** present the outcome to your customer and let them give you more direction on which models/outputs are more meaningful for them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Also good points. What I might try and do is train a regression model; convert the predicted values to pass/fail based on the threshold; compare the F1 score/confusion matrix output to the output from a classification model. I would hope I could get the regression model to outperform the classification model and as you say I will then also be armed with more information on the how and why of the predictor tool.